# I'm getting two NullPointerExceptions and I'm not sure how to fix

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm making a doubley linked circular list that holds vectors and I cannot  figure out how to fix two NullPointerExceptions that I'm getting. Both of them are with my add methods, one add method inserts an object at the end of the list and the other inserts the object at the given index. Here is my code that is in question.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Vector;

public class DList<T> implements ADTListInterface<T> {
private int size;
private int BUCKET;
private DListNode head;
private DListNode last;

public DList() {
    head = new DListNode(null);
    head.next = last;
    head.prev = head;
    BUCKET = 1;
}

public DList(int bucket){
    if (bucket <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have a bucket lower than 1");

    this.BUCKET = bucket;
    head = new DListNode(null);
    head.next = last;
    head.prev = head;
}

private class DListNode {
    private Vector<T> item;   //Line 29
    private DListNode next;   //Line 30
    private DListNode prev;

    public DListNode(T o) {
        this(o, null, null);
    }

    public DListNode(T o, DListNode next, DListNode prev) {
        item = new Vector<T>(BUCKET);

        item.add(o);
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        if (this.item.size() == this.item.capacity()) {
            DListNode newNode = new DListNode(item, this.next, this);
            this.next = newNode;
        }

        else {
            insertAfter(item);
        }
    }

    public void add(T item, int idx) {
        if (this.item.size() == this.item.capacity()) {
            DListNode newNode = new DListNode(this.item.elementAt(BUCKET), this.next, this);
            this.next = newNode;
        }
        else {
            this.item.add(idx, item);
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(T o){
        if (item.indexOf(o) != -1){
            item.remove(o);
            if (item.size() == 0){
                this.prev.next = this.next;
                this.next.prev = this.prev;
            }
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void insertAfter(T item) {
        next = new DListNode(item, next, prev);
        next.next.prev = next;
    }

    public DListNode nth(int index) {
        if (index == 1)
            return this;
        else if (index < 0 || next == null) {
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("No Such Element");
        } else
            return next.nth(index - 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void add(T o) {

    DListNode last = head;
    while (last.item.size() >= BUCKET && last.next != head) {
        last = last.next;
    }

    if (last.item.size() == BUCKET) { //Line 102
        DListNode n = new DListNode(o, head, last);
        head.prev.next = n;
        head.prev = n;
        size++;
    } else {
        last.item.add(o);
    }

}

    @Override
public void add(T o, int index) {
    DListNode temp = head, testNext;
    int count = 0;

    while (count+1 <= index) {
        count += temp.item.size();
        temp = temp.next;
        if (temp == head) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out Of Bounds!");
        }
    }
    testNext = temp.next;   //Line 126
    temp.add(o, index);
    if (testNext != temp.next)
        size++;
}
```

}

And the two errors that I'm getting are:

1. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at DList$DListNode.access$0(DList.java:29)
   at DList.add(DList.java:102)
   at DListNodeDriver.main(DListNodeDriver.java:7)
2. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at DList$DListNode.access$1(DList.java:30)
   at DList.add(DList.java:126)
   at DListNodeDriver.main(DListNodeDriver.java:6)

   Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Main Method

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DListNodeDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DList<String> students = new DList<String>();
        students.add("Other", 1);
        students.add("New", 3);
        Iterator<String> t = students.iterator();
        while (t.hasNext()) {
            String temp = t.next();
            StdOut.println("Student: " + temp);
        }

    }
}

import java.util.Iterator;

public class DListNodeDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DList<String> students = new DList<String>();
        students.add("Other");
        students.add("New");
        Iterator<String> t = students.iterator();
        while (t.hasNext()) {
            String temp = t.next();
            StdOut.println("Student: " + temp);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your main method? I think we can help only by seeing the main method

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use e.g. LinkedList?

Comment: Yes.Because he is trying to implement one.

Comment: Added main method... Hopefully I didn't derp somewhere lol

Comment: *I'm getting two errors in line ...* Boy, you have to tell us where are those two lines, notice that we haven't line numbers in stackoverflow =).

Comment: I did add the lines on the right hand side of the code denoted with // then the line number.

Comment: Line 126 is near the bottom of all the code, line 102 is a bit above that. The error is happening in the main method on line 6 of both main methods. The lines "students.add("Other")" and "students.add("Other", 1)". Please let me know if you need any other info

Answer (score 1):

Your `temp` is null for obvious reasons. Step through it:

1. Parameterless Constructor -> `head.next` is `null`.
2. `students.add("other",1);` -> `temp = temp.next` in the loop and therefor `null`.

Similar problem happens in `students.add("other")`.

I would do something like this, based on your implementations:

```
@Override
public void add(T o, int index) {
    DListNode temp = head
    int count = 0;

    // < instead of <= because if index = size, your temp will be null otherwise.
    // if index = 1 , you'll want to add after head. Watch out for index > size! 
    // It is an IndexOutOfBounds, index = size => add behind last element.
    while (count+1 < index) { 
        count++;
        if( temp.next == null ) { /*Handle that case */ }
        else {temp = temp.next;}
        //if (temp == head) {
        //    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out Of Bounds!");
        //}
    }
    // temp should now be the element just before the index at which to insert.
    // I'd do a temp.insertAfter( o );

    /* DO YOUR ADDING HERE*/
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following you.

Comment: In the first main, you init the "students" with the parameter-less constructor. This leaves `head.next` pointing to `null`. In the add()-method of the DList, you first set `temp = head`, then in the while-loop, you set `temp = temp.next` which is `head.next` which is `null`. Then in line 126 you try to access `temp`. `temp`is `null` which throws NPE.

Comment: I don't see how when I init "students" how it is parameter-less. I have "students.add("Other") as my parameter. Or am I missing something? Sorry I'm super tired and have been working on this for too long.

Comment: :) `DList<String> students = new DList<String>();` I'm talking about this _parameter-less_ **constructor**. It leaves the `next` field pointing to null which causes your NPE. You'll have to check them for being `null`. Try to step it through with the debugger and you'll see.

Comment: Okay sorry I'm fairly new to this, how would I go about doing that? And thank you for responding too =) I'm just a lil brain dead right now

Comment: Okay I went through it with the debugger and I see how it is being set to null. I just do not know how to fix this though.

Comment: Nevermind. You'll have to add lines like `if( temp == null ) ...` and do "special case handling". One more tip: You should recheck your add(item, index) ...

Comment: Ugg I give up nothing is working. I tried adding some special case lines and those aren't doing anything. I'm going to bed for now. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to know.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

You know the max size of the container and you manage yourself the insertion, I suggest to use T[] in place of Vector. You may expect better performances (no lock) and more explicit errors.

In the code sample below, replace Object by parametrized argument T

http://fr.scribd.com/doc/81926911/37/The-Circular-Linked-List

Comment: I had originally attempted to do that but, I kept getting errors that I could not make an Array with generics and opted to use vectors and learn the vector API.